# Collapse fails to update with dynamic ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a simple collapse.

```
<ul collapse="isCollapsed">
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the controller:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('CollapseDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.isCollapsed = true;
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.add = function() {
    $scope.items.push(Math.random());
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZYE3A4gt2I3JZgOEXxhf?p=preview

When I toggle the isCollapsed from true to false and add more items to the list, the collapse height is not updated. It does not happen when *isCollapsed* is initialized with false or when I toggle the collapse again.

I'm not sure if it's a bug or it works as expected.

EDIT: The problem is when toggle isCollapsed to false, if there is no item (height: 0px), the collapse will not set the height attr to auto, which will make the collapse update its height.

Comment: What do you mean by collapse height? How do you know it is not updating? I tried your code and it seems when iscollapse is false,the add function still adding item to the list but just now showing since it is in collapse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is confirmed as a bug. Please refer to this github issue https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2836